# Conditional WHERE in SQL QUERY

Tags: sql

I have this database:

[image]

I'm using SQL code in R but the point of this post is how to make a query in SQL.

I`ve made this query:

```
> se<- sqldf("select ALUMNO , ESTADO as FIRSTANSWERALG, NIVEL from stbase where CURSO='Algebra' AND NPREGUNTA='pregunta 1' AND NIVEL='BASICO 1' ")
> head(se)
                          ALUMNO FIRSTANSWERALG    NIVEL
1      ABANTO PICHIGUA JOSE LUIS       Correcta BASICO 1
2     AGUILAR GUTIERREZ KIMBERLY     Incorrecta BASICO 1
3   ARANGO MENDIETA FREDY JULIAN       Correcta BASICO 1
4     ARIAS OROSCO SHEYLA ANDREA       Correcta BASICO 1
5 AYALA CORNEJO KARLA FRANSHESKA       Correcta BASICO 1
6          CARDENAS SONCCO HEIDY       Correcta BASICO 1
```

This query selects the answer of the first question(PREGUNTA 1) in the subject 'Algebra'. However, I would like to make a query to select the answer of other questions and other subjects as well. For example:

```
                       ALUMNO    FIRSTANSWERALG    THIRDANSWERARI              NIVEL
1      ABANTO PICHIGUA JOSE LUIS       Correcta     Correcta                  BASICO 1
2     AGUILAR GUTIERREZ KIMBERLY     Incorrecta     Correcta                  BASICO 1
3   ARANGO MENDIETA FREDY JULIAN       Correcta     En blanco                 BASICO 1
4     ARIAS OROSCO SHEYLA ANDREA       Correcta     Incorrecta                BASICO 1
5 AYALA CORNEJO KARLA FRANSHESKA       Correcta     Correcta                  BASICO 1
6          CARDENAS SONCCO HEIDY       Correcta     Correcta                  BASICO 1
```

In this database the third answer in the subject 'Arithmetic' is added. So how can I add columns of the answer of a certain subject.

EDIT: The set of values of CURSO are: 'Aritmetica, 'Algebra', 'Geometria'. CURSO in english means subject. THIRDANSWEARI means the answer of 'Pregunta 3' in the subject 'Aritmetica'.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but I suspect you just need to write a JOIN.

Comment: THIRDANSWERARI means NPREGUNTA="QUESTION 3" and curso="ARITMETICA". Given that I wrote where curso="ALGEBRA" , I don`t know how to fix the query.

Comment: Please don't shout. Or is this Oracle?

Comment: It's a library to write SQL sentences in R.

Answer (score 0):

I see this to get what you want is not very hard. I believe the output from the query below is what you are looking for. Let me know if it worked. Thank you!

```
select 
ALUMNO, 
ESTADO as FIRSTANSWERALG, 
NIVEL,
NPREGUNTA as THIRDANSWERARI

from stbase 

-- (remove this if 2 lines below get removed) --
where 
-- (remove this if you want to show more questions) --
CURSO='Aritmetica' 
-- (remove this if you don't want to limit your output to 'BASICO 1' in your NiVEL column) --
AND NIVEL='BASICO 1'
```

---

I am trying to understand your question. So far, I know that you are trying to add a column to the query output named as THIRDANSWERARI. My question is the data in the THIRDANSWERARI column is in your selected database or is something you want to put in manually?

Comment: It's in the databse itself. THIRDANSWERARI means NPREGUNTA="QUESTION 3" and curso="ARITMETICA". Given that I wrote where curso="ALGEBRA" , I don`t know how to fix the query.

Comment: FIRSTANSWERALG and THIRDANSWERARI referst to two the answer of two different subjects and are columns which appears as a result of the same query.

Comment: Yea, I got that. try the query attached above to see if that is what you want.

Comment: I`ve tried and the output is not the expected one. For example in the column THIRDANSWEARI the values are 'pregunta1' but the values should be 'Correcta' or 'Incorrecta' or 'En blanco', the same set of values of FIRSTANSWEALG. The expected output is the post.

Comment: Does the NPREGUNTA contains the same values like  'Correcta' or 'Incorrecta' or 'En blanco' as ESTADO? Or maybe 'pregunta 1'? Can you provide a screen shot of the database table containing NPREGUNTA column? Since the one showing above is not NPREGUNTA since it is showing like N<>.PREGUNTA

Comment: In your query the values of NPREGUNTA are ' pregunta 1' , that`s not the expect output. Please, check the data base attached. The values of subject are not only Aritmetica.

Comment: Yea, I edited the query above, and have given you a couple of options. Please try it out and let me know the results. It should be a pretty simple question.

Comment: In your query when you write 'NPREGUNTA as THIRDANSWERARI', it doesn't give the set of values 'Correcta' , 'Incorrecta' , ' En blanco' as expected.

Comment: Oh, finally, i get what you are saying. I will post another solution. Please check the update.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this time will work since I understand what you were saying now :D

```
select
t1.ALUMNO,
t1.FIRSTANSWERALG,
t2.THIRDANSWERALG,
t1.NIVEL

FROM
(select 
ALUMNO, 
ESTADO as FIRSTANSWERALG, 
NIVEL

from stbase 

where 
CURSO='Aritmetica' 
AND NPREGUNTA='pregunta 1'
AND NIVEL='BASICO 1') t1

JOIN
(select 
ALUMNO, 
ESTADO as THIRDANSWERALG, 
NIVEL

from stbase 

where 
CURSO='Aritmetica' 
AND NPREGUNTA='pregunta 3'
AND NIVEL='BASICO 1') t2 ON t1.ALUMNO = t2.ALUMNO
```

PLEASE NOTE: You can change CURSO value in this query to get answers for other subjects. For example: CURSO='Algebra' in both WHERE statement above to get answers for 'Algebra' instead of 'Aritmetica'